# ASP.NET C# Web application - CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two checkboxes, what I want to do is, when I check one, the other should be disabled, I always do this in C# Windows application and it is my first try with ASP.NET is there a way to do that without using combocheckboxes?
here is my method which does not work:

```
protected void checkplan0_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkplan0.Checked == true)
    {
        checkplan1.Enabled = false;
    }
    if (checkplan0.Checked == false)
    {
        checkplan1.Enabled = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: So are you getting any error ?, or what else ?

Comment: No error, it is just not doing anything.

Comment: Check the answers. It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, as you mentioned that you are from windows form background I assume this is what you are missing

```
<asp:CheckBox 
      ID="checkplan0" 
      runat="server" 
      AutoPostBack="true" 
      OnCheckedChanged="checkplan0_CheckedChanged" />
```

Set `AutoPostBack = "true"` setting this true will mean on check of checkbox a postback will be sent to server and the code that you have written on Check Change will execute.

Comment: Thank you. I have one question, since the checkbox is actually at the bottom of the page, when I click check for example, it always takes me to the top of the screen, is there away I can prevent that and stay where I am at the page? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, you need to set maintainscrollposition read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said you'll need to have autopostback="true", also it might be worth considering using radio buttons, as only one radio button in a group can be checked at a time.

```
<asp:RadioButton id="radioplan0" Checked="True" GroupName="RadioPlan" runat="server" Autopostback="true" />
<asp:RadioButton id="radioplan1" Checked="False" GroupName="RadioPlan" runat="server" Autopostback="true" />
```

Then nothing needs to be added to the code behind to toggle the other options off.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good. But as you are beginner. You might be missing simple thing in source page.

**=>** Check whether Your `AutoPostBack` set to `true` for your checkbox. If not add **AutoPostBack ="true"**